# MongoDB: aggregation after lookup causes timeout in small dataset

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a collection of documents as follows, on which I would like to perform a lookup over another one and an aggregation:

```
{
transactions: {
  Codice articolo:"039180094"
  Tipo di acquisto:"D"
  },
transaction_value:9.912
}
```

Current aggregation is:

```
[{
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'product_to_categories', 
            'localField': 'transactions.Codice articolo', 
            'foreignField': 'MIN_SAN', 
            'as': 'product_info'
        }
    }, {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$product_info', 
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': False
        }
    }, {
        '$addFields': {
            'prod_category': {
                '$toString': '$product_info.DESC_GRU1'
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$project': {
            '_id': 0, 
            'transactions.Tipo di acquisto': 1, 
            'prod_category': 1, 
            'transaction_value': 1
        }
    }, {
        '$group': {
            '_id': [
                '$transactions.Tipo di acquisto', '$prod_category'
            ], 
            'financial_impact': {
                '$sum': '$transaction_value'
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$sort': {
            'financial_impact': -1
        }
    }]
```

The aggregation in Compass correctly runs until the group step, which causes a timeout error or runs indefinitely even using Compass' sample mode.

I've tried to exclude the lookup operation from the aggregation and it correctly performs the group step (to illustrate, grouping only by "$transactions.Tipo di acquisto"). Likewise, raising Compass' "Max time" value to 90000000 but the result doesn't change.

[image]

As a final note, the variable "Tipo di acquisto" can either be equal to "D" or "Nan" (Double type).

How could I fix that?

Comment: Try the group `_id` as an object with keys, not as array

Comment: {$group: {_id:{a: '$transactions.Tipo di acquisto', b: '$prod_category'},  'financial_impact': {'$sum': '$transaction_value'}}}

Comment: I'm unfortunately experiencing the same problem ...

Comment: Do you have an index on `"MIN_SAN"` in the `product_to_categories` collection?  Do you need to retrieve the entire document from `product_to_categories`, or could a `"pipeline"` in `"$lookup"` minimize what is returned?

Comment: Indeed; adding an index to "MIN_SAN" dramatically reduced the time. What would a pipeline to retrieve only a single field named "PROD_DESCR1" from product_to_categories look like? If you add an answer I will be more than happy to accept that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an index on field `Tipo di acquisto`. To create index in mongo CLI use:

```js
dn.transactions.createIndex({"Tipo di acquisto": 1});
```

Of course you can create index in compass via >Indexes tab >Create Index.

BTW It's a very bad idea to name fields like `Tipo di acquisto`. Stick to camelCase notation instead: `tipoDiAcqisto`.

Comment: I tried but it is stuck; it seems like the lookup operation is somehow interfering with the pipeline, although it does not report any problem at that level. Any guess?

Comment: I know about the naming convention but data is from an external provider and belongs to a "lake"; thank you